# Avoiding duplicate content with dynamic URLs

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, sitemap

So I'm using mod_rewrite and making a sitemap daily for my pages(products for sale). Google reads and indexes the URL. However, if I change the title of the item, the url will be changed and updated in the sitemap, so search engine will index duplicate content, with updated title. For example:

example.com/green-dress/54325

(domain / title / id)

If i decide to update title such as example.com/green-dress-with-small-rip/54325

As you can see, it has the same item id at the end. it is the same item, except with an update now. But google, unlike a me, doesn't know that it is suppose to update the item, because it obviously doesn't know that the last section of url is the item ID.

So the question is... how should i work around this? One way is to not mod-rewrite, but I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Thanks,
Dav

Comment: Your generated site map does not contain the dupes though right?  You want to flush things from Google's index?  Not sure I follow.  Maybe this? https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/indexing#removal

Comment: the sitemap is always updated to only what is available, my scripts do not ADD to the sitemap unless it is a new item. It always updates items each day. Make sense I hope...

Comment: Yes. the title can be anything! as long as the slash afterward has the item ID, it brings up the item based on the ID.

Comment: @Supericy Google treats different addresses with different title and same ID's as duplicates. It is not good for SEO, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First possibility is to store old URI's and perform `301 Moved Permanently` redirect to new URI. But what we made in our project is we compared title in address with actual title in controller, and, if it does not match, make 301 redirect to address with correct title. After some time Google will not scan old pages. Our solution is more universal, as I think

Comment: Timur, thanks for the answer, but what is the best way? I tried to put it in .htaccess (the 301 redirect), but it seems to conflict with my re-write code. It does redirect to the new URL, BUT..... it adds the "?id=itemnumber" variable the end of the redirected URL(i'm guessing from the rewrite rule in .htaccess)

Comment: @DaveFes As i wrote, in my opinion, it is better to compare titles in controllers PHP code and redirect using `header` function: `header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\nLocation:http://example.com/".$correctTitle."/".$id);`

Comment: I finally got it to work!!!!! What you were saying was right, but the problem is that you said controller, which I didn't understand til today. I came up with the idea myself and then I re-read your answer and it was the same thing lol. IF you told me "compare URI with title in the database which holds all the products, and then redirect to the database URI if the current URI doesn't match", then I would have understood it. You said controller, so I was confused. Not your fault, but mine! Thanks so much! SOOO HAPPY RIGHT NOW!!!